# Any regexp to transform a single new line to double new lines?

Tags: ruby, regex

For instance:

`Foo\n\nBar`

Would stay the same, but:

`Foo\nBar` would change to `Foo\n\nBar`

I'm looking for a regexp to do this, hopefully it would recognize other forms of new lines like `\r` and `\r\n`.

Comment: What do you want `\r` and `\r\n` to become?

Comment: As long as the end result is 2 new lines I'd be a happy boy :D

Comment: What about 3 or more newlines, ie: `Foo\n\n\n\nBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Foo\nBar".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "\n\n")   # => "Foo\n\nBar"
"Foo\n\nBar".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "\n\n") # => "Foo\n\nBar"
"Foo\rBar".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "\n\n")   # => "Foo\n\nBar"
"Foo\r\nBar".gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "\n\n") # => "Foo\n\nBar"
```